# Why there is no online references found for Windows Printer Functions SetPrinterHTMLView and GetPrinterHTMLView?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, printing, visual-c++-6

I am using VC++ 6.0 and on searching some functions for Application Printing capabilities some functions of SetPrinterHTMLView and GetPrinterHTMLView been found.

But no reference can be found in Google for the same and in MSDN too.

Can anyone point me to the right reference for the same?

Comment: I can confirm that these functions do not appear in `winspool.h` in VS2005 or VS2012 so I assume they were never implemented and therefore no documentation was written for them.

Comment: @user1793036 Yes, I saw that too. But in VC6 it is in the Winspool.h and implemented too :(

Comment: Microsoft went a little bonkers around 1994 when they realized the Internet was getting to be a big deal and they were falling behind.  Most of the early stuff got whacked again, later.

Comment: It might be a Windows 95 thing that got axed in XP.  It's not defined in any of the SDKs I have access to, dating back to NT 3.51.